# Automatically apply Kotlin code formatting to [android-jetpack-compose] questions

Tags: feature-request, tags, code-formatting

I have noticed that applying some tags automatically adds code highlighting to code blocks.

Obviously all language tags apply the appropriate formatting, but some technology tags also do this without any language tag, for example [android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android) seems very likely to apply Java or Kotlin formatting.

Using Jetpack Compose requires Kotlin code usage ([maintainer confirmation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66433621/3585796)), so it would be nice to automatically apply formatting to [android-jetpack-compose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-jetpack-compose).

Comment: You can check what code formatting a tag gives by looking at the [bottom of the info page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/android/info). Android has "default" highlighting so that it auto detects what's best (as a variety of languages are used).

Comment: @Laurel thanks, I see now, can a specific language be bind to a tag? Should it be done through meta, or there's an other way? I can't see such an options during wiki edit

Comment: A meta request like this is the right way to get syntax highlighting as you need a diamond mod to edit it. Also, yes, a specific highlighting language can be assigned as long as the highlighter supports it (Kotlin is available; see its specific tag for an example).